# MatDatePicker shows up at the bottom of the page and with broken style

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using angular 8. In my app.module.ts I added:

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
```

and I added them in the @NgModuel imports

In the component html I have:

```
<input [matDatepicker]="LMPDatepicker" formControlName="LMP" class="t-field t-field--date menstural-field" aria-labelledby="menstural_LMP" max="{{lmpmax}}" min="{{lmpmin}}">
<mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="LMPDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #LMPDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

When I click on the toggle it scrolls to the bottom of the page where the Datepicker is open and does actually choose the dates correctly, but the style and position is completely messed up...

[image]

This happens anywhere in my project that I add a datepicker.

Answer (score 5):

After adding @import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
to the styles.css everything works fine. https://material.angular.io/guide/theming